# Git, PyCharm. Removing a folder from git

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I am not a git pro. I use PyCharm to add/commit/push files to my github repository.

I deleted a folder inside my project's root (using right-click -> delete). I pushed changes but I can still see the folder in github.

In my local repository I do and get this:

```
$ git rm -rf uc011
fatal: pathspec 'uc011' did not match any files
```

uc011 is the folder that I deleted using PyCharm.

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the deletion of your directory to be reflected in the remote, you need to force push to it - 
`git push -f origin master` or `git push origin master --force`.

This means you want to ask git to override all of your remote's code with your local one. So whenever you do this, be sure that's what you want.

Comment: I am sorry. It doesn't work. Although I get this: `Everything up-to-date`, the folder still shows in github

Comment: Do an `rm -rf` to the folder and then commit and then force push. When git says everything is up to date, it means you haven't changed anything. So the deletion didn't actually happen.

Comment: Thanks. I did `rm -rf uc011` and surprisingly it didn't complain. Although the folder was not there before (I can assure you about that because I did an `ls` just before `rm -rf`). Then I committed changes and force-push them and it worked! However it is trange to me that it deleted a folder that was not showing before.